# Simplify repetitive select, copy, paste values in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, copy-paste

Is there a simpler way of doing this so that I don't have to manually type in "1", and "M38+n" etc.

```
Range("M6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
Range("M28").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("M38").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
Range("M35").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("N38").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
Range("M6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
Range("M28").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("M39").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
Range("M35").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("N39").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

And further to this, can a similar solution be had for the following:

```
Range("M6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
Range("U38").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(R[-12]C[-7]:R[-12]C[16])"
Range("U38").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("W38").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
Range("V38").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(R[-5]C[-8]:R[-5]C[15])"
Range("V38").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("X38").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
Range("M6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"
Range("U39").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(R[-13]C[-7]:R[-13]C[16])"
Range("U39").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("W39").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
Range("V39").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(R[-6]C[-8]:R[-6]C[15])"
Range("V39").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("X39").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
```

In both instances, the numerals in M6 reference arrays from a separate sheet (using an index function), the results are then pasted as values into a table. In the first example, a single value is used, whilst in the second, the highest value is used (Max function). It can become time consuming when M6 requires, say, values from 1 to 300. I imagine a loop or something like that can be used, but haven't a clue where to start.

Many thanks.

Update:
As requested below, please see some additional information on the code, and how it can become time consuming to edit/scale it.

For the first set of code, putting number "1" (or any other number for that matter) in M6 gives a result in M28 and also in M35, which is then copied and pasted (as a value) in M38 and N38 respectively. The next iteration repeats the process, but instead uses number "2" (referencing a separate array) for input. The values are again obtained from M28 and M35, but they are then pasted in the row immediately below the previous set of results i.e. M39 and N39. I must find a way to be able to repeat this process over and over, such that entering any numeral into M6 will paste the resulting values from M28 and M35 into the corresponding rows i.e. 1 > 38, 2 > 39, 3 > 40 and so on.

For the second set of code, a similar solution is needed. This time the maximum values (resulting from changes made in M6) from the arrays  specified (using relative "coordinates") must be pasted into neighbouring cells i.e. same rows as code above, but shifted to the right in another table. The major difference here is that the formula is using relative rows and columns to denote the array.

Comment: This question is well written but the code really is quite hard to follow, you might get a better\quicker response if you could describe the code, what is happening and what you want to happen a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks, @GaryEvans. I will edit the question - hopefully I get some feedback :)

Comment: Its okay, I solved it. For anyone who's interested: